# Can I update the User Profile pictures, without having My Site?

Tags: user-profile

Can I update the User Profile pictures, without having My Site ?

The command `Update-SPProfilePhotoStore` needs My Site host, which is not configured in my environment, is it mandatory to update my profile's pictures?

Comment: Do you have UserProfile Sync enabled? Are you trying to sync the photos from Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

You must at least have a MySite Host, which is where the pictures are stored (/sites/mysites/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/domain_username_ThumbSize.jpg).